# When using Jackson, System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().readTree(jsonStringObject)); prints the JSON with random spaces in between keys and values

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

A very strange behavior. When I just print the `System.out.println(jsonStringObject);` it prints the JSON properly and well, but when I use Jackson's API, namely `new ObjectMapper().readTree(jsonStringObject);`it incorporates some random spaces.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A very strange behavior.

Indeed. But see what the [`JsonNode`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) class documentation says about the [`toString()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#toString--) method:

> Method that will produce developer-readable representation of the node; which may **or may not** be as valid JSON. If you want valid JSON output (or output formatted using one of other Jackson supported data formats) make sure to use `ObjectMapper` or `ObjectWriter` to serialize an instance, for example:
>
> ```
> String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(rootNode);
> ```

Comment: not sure why I haven't upvoted this before, but get your score now, after three years. :)

Comment: Does this mean that registering modules will not work when deserialising with toString() ? I get ````Java 8 date/time type `java.time.ZonedDateTime` not supported by default: add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310" to enable handling```` when using toString() on ObjectNode instance. However, using mapper. writeValueAsString(objNode) serializes datetime. I am creating objNode from the same mapper instance

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the ObjectMapper directly to deserialize the JsonNode produces by the readTree method, as it's recommended on the API documentation of [JsonNode.toString()](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#toString()).

```
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(rootNode);
```

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the behavior for toString() has changed in 2.10

toString() now returns a valid JSON

> Method that will produce (as of Jackson 2.10) valid JSON using default settings of databind, as String.

[Documentation Jackson 2.11](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#toString--)